# Scaling 3d map after it is built

Tags: slam, mapping, 3d-slam

Suppose you are running an algorithm which doesn't provide absolute scale during initial map construction.

Is there a way to integrate scale information after the fact assuming all points are approximately correct? Is it as simple as multiplying all coordinates by a constant?